# Loading twitter tweets 410 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, tweets

I'm having problems loading tweets. I want to load the tweets for ex. from "BachelorGDM".
(https://twitter.com/BachelorGDM)

This is what I do in my javascript file:

```
var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/BachelorGDM.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4';

var script = document.createElement('script');  
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    document.body.appendChild(script);

function twitterCallback(tweets)
{
    console.log(tweets);
}
```

When I try this I get this error:

> GET https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/BachelorGDM.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4 410 (Gone)

The strange thing is that this worked yesterdag :/ 
I already tried loading tweets from another user but same response.

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the newer version I found this tutorial: 
http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

Answer (score 3):

If you open [your url](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/BachelorGDM.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4) in browser, it says:

> The Twitter REST API v1 will soon stop functioning. Please migrate to
>   API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.

So, you need to use newer version.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter stopped suppoting their API v1, and moved on to V1.1. This version has an extra layer of security (which is also needed for public accounts). If you're using PHP, [this tutorial](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/) will help you to display tweets again.